# Create various matrix on java

Tags: java, matrix, input, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to make a Java application that takes a number as input and creates various matrices.

What's the best way to make this?

I've made this, and then I've tried to make it by array of arrays.

```
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int max = 0;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Number of matrix?");
        max = scan.nextInt();

        int[] matrius = new int[max];
        int[][] matriu = new int[2][2];

        matrius[0] = matriu[2][2];
        matrius[1] = matriu[2][2];

        for(int i = 0; i < matrius.length; i++){
            matrius[i] = i;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < matrius.length; i++){
            System.out.println(matrius[i]);
        }           

    }

}
```

Thank you!

Comment: what does the user enter ? whether he wants a 3 x 3 or 2 x2 or 4 x 4 matrix? that no ?

Comment: Hello! The user enters how many matrix wants to make, not it's dimension.

Comment: okay. so the user enters he wants to make 4 matrices . now where do u get their dimension from ? or is the dimension unknown

Comment: The dimension it's 2x2 by the moment. I only want to learn how I can make many matrix by entering a number.

Comment: @ZBlond and what would you do with this `max` variable ? right now you're not really using it in any meaningful way.

Comment: Hello! I don't know what's the next step. The max variable it's the number of matrix to make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a list to hold all your 2D matrices of 2 x 2. List has initial capacity entered by user i.e max.

Now loop and create 2D arrays and add them to the list.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int max = 0;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Number of matrix?");
        max = scan.nextInt();

        List<int[][]> allMatrices = new ArrayList<int[][]>(max);

        for(int i = 0; i < max; i++){
            int x[][]=new int [2][2];
            allMatrices.add(x);
        }


  // To acces the 2 D arrays 

    foreach(int [][] x : allMatrices){


    for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++)
     {
       for(int j=0;j<x[i].length ;j++)
         {
       // do some operation on    x[i][j]
          }
     }

          }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm trying to understand this structure because I'm a beginner of ArrayList.

Comment: arraylist.get[i] will get you the array at mentioned index. arraylist.add() helps u add. u can also insert , remove etc. Check this page:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is using `OpenMapRealMatrix` of commons-math project.

This object can store a matrix with any number of rows and columns and it offers a lot of useful methods: copy, create new matrix, multiply, etc...

Take a look at this page:

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/linear/OpenMapRealMatrix.html